# Symfony2/Twig how to create dynamically generated content that will display properly depending of field type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's assume I have a class with a datetime field, a key to a user and a simple string.

As I will track all the changes to certain fields, let's assume those fields are  logged/versioned (I'll probably use the StofDoctrineExtentionsBundle).

I need a "general logger viewer" to which I'll pass the field, and it will display a table with all the versions of the field value, who did it an when.

The challenge is displaying the value: for a string I simply get it, for a user (which is in the form of a user object) I might want to display "Name, Surname", for a datetime I'll have to print a decent date. But the same "general logger viewer" would have to work for every kind of variable, so I was thinking of having something like "if the value is of the type user display this, if string display that etc...". So basically I need a way to get the type. But it must be a custom type (for instance the Doctrine value could be an integer, but in reality I'm storing the information for an enum, e.g. "Project Type [0=>'IT', 1=>'non-IT']" so basically for each field I'd have a sort of "getType(field)" and that would return the custom type field, and according to that I'd print one thing or another.

How could I do that?

One way I foresee is creating the function name dynamically, so when I'm trying to access the type of the attribute `user`, I'd simply do:

```
$myEntity = ...whatever
$fieldName = 'user';
$varFunction = 'get'.$fieldName.'Type';
$type = $myEntity->varFunction();
```

But I'm missing how I could call the function (code above of course does not work, the creation of a function name dynamically can be done AFAIK, but I don't know how to call when it's supposed to be a function inside another entity...

SN

Comment: You should use the Symfony `PropertyAccessor` component. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30300353/1791606

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had solved the problem by simply using: call_user_func('AppBundle\Entity\\'.$entityName.'::get'.$fieldNameFirstUpper.'Type');

Comment: You could do it far easier using `$type = $myEntity->{$varFunction}()` but it (as well as the `call_user_func`) is no where near as usable as the `PropertyAccessor`.

Comment: In my case also the entity name is dynamic

Comment: I think `${$entityName}->{$varFunction}()` would work then although you are using static methods so `${$entityName}::{$varFunction}()` would seem to fit your methods. Yours works any way though so...